# Combine two filters with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, filter

Hi I created an product page with two filter - price range and checkboxes. I am able to run both filter separately, but when I tried to combine both filters, one overlaps the others. I was searching in the internet but I couldn't really find a solution. Is there a way I can filter products with two different filters The codes below are my product page and my javascript codes

product.php

```js
    // CHECKBOXES
    // CHECKBOXES
    var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
    var filterFunc = function() {
    
    var selectedFilters = {};

    $filterCheckboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() {

        if (!selectedFilters.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) {
        selectedFilters[this.name] = [];
        }

        selectedFilters[this.name].push(this.value);
    });

    var $filteredResults = $('.productFilter');

    $.each(selectedFilters, function(name, filterValues) {

        $filteredResults = $filteredResults.filter(function() {

        var matched = false,
            currentFilterValues = $(this).data('category').split(' ');

        $.each(currentFilterValues, function(_, currentFilterValue) {
            if ($.inArray(currentFilterValue, filterValues) != -1) {
            matched = true;
            return false;
            }
        });

        return matched;

        });
    });

    $('.productFilter').hide().filter($filteredResults).show();
    }

    $filterCheckboxes.on('change', filterFunc);  
    // CHECKBOXES
    // CHECKBOXES


        // PRICE RANGE
        // PRICE RANGE
        $('#price_range').slider({
        range:true,
        min:0,
        max:1000,
        values:[0, 1000], 
        step:50, 
        slide: function(e, ui) {
            $('#price_show').html(ui.values[0] + ' - ' + ui.values[1]);
            var min = Math.floor(ui.values[0]);
            $('#hidden_minimum_price').html(min + 'm');

            var max = Math.floor(ui.values[1]);
            
            $('#hidden_maximum_price').html(max + '.');

            $('.productFilter').each(function() {
                var minPrice = (min);
                var maxPrice = (max);

                var value = $(this).data('start-price');
                if ((parseInt(maxPrice) >= parseInt(value) && (parseInt(minPrice) <= parseInt(value))) ){
                    $(this).show();
                } else {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    // PRICE RANGE
    // PRICE RANGE
```

```html
                    <div class="list-group">
                        <h3>Price</h3>
                        <input type="hidden" id="hidden_minimum_price" value="0" /> <!-- 'value' will not display anything - is used for function at line 191 -->
                        <input type="hidden" id="hidden_maximum_price" value="1000" /> <!-- 'value' will not display anything - is used for function at line 191 -->
                        <p id="price_show">0 - 1000</p>
                        <div id="price_range"></div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="list-group">
                        <h3>Type</h3>
                        <div style="height: 200px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;"> <!-- 'overflow-y' will create the vertical scroll effect when elements are outside the box/ 'overflow-x' will hide the horizontal elements outside the box -->
                            <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox"class="common_selector brand" value="Headphone_Speaker" id="Headphone_Speaker">Headphone & Speaker</label> <!-- 'value' is the value that will be sent to a server when a form is submitted -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" class="common_selector brand" value="Chair" id="Chair">Chair</label> <!-- 'value' is the value that will be sent to a server when a form is submitted -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" class="common_selector brand" value="Cabinet" id="Cabinet">Cabinet</label> <!-- 'value' is the value that will be sent to a server when a form is submitted -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" class="common_selector brand" value="Table" id="Table">Table</label> <!-- 'value' is the value that will be sent to a server when a form is submitted -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" class="common_selector brand" value="Box" id="Box">Box</label> <!-- 'value' is the value that will be sent to a server when a form is submitted -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                                        <div class="productFilter col-md-4 text-center" data-category="Headphone_Speaker" data-start-price="600">
                        <div class="product">
                            <div class="product-grid" style="background-image:url(images/product-2.jpg);">
                                <div class="inner">
                                    <p>
                                        <a href="product.php?id=2" class="icon"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                                        <a href="product.php?id=2" class="icon"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="desc">
                                <h3><a href="product.php?id=2">PAVILION SPEAKER</a></h3>
                                <span class="price">$600</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                                            <div class="productFilter col-md-4 text-center" data-category="Chair" data-start-price="780">
                        <div class="product">
                            <div class="product-grid" style="background-image:url(images/product-3.jpg);">
                                <div class="inner">
                                    <p>
                                        <a href="product.php?id=3" class="icon"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                                        <a href="product.php?id=3" class="icon"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="desc">
                                <h3><a href="product.php?id=3">LIGOMANCER</a></h3>
                                <span class="price">$780</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                                            <div class="productFilter col-md-4 text-center" data-category="Cabinet" data-start-price="800">
                        <div class="product">
                            <div class="product-grid" style="background-image:url(images/product-4.jpg);">
                                <div class="inner">
                                    <p>
                                        <a href="product.php?id=4" class="icon"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                                        <a href="product.php?id=4" class="icon"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="desc">
                                <h3><a href="product.php?id=4">ALATO CABINET</a></h3>
                                <span class="price">$800</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                                            <div class="productFilter col-md-4 text-center" data-category="Headphone_Speaker" data-start-price="100">
                        <div class="product">
                            <div class="product-grid" style="background-image:url(images/product-5.jpg);">
                                <div class="inner">
                                    <p>
                                        <a href="product.php?id=5" class="icon"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                                        <a href="product.php?id=5" class="icon"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="desc">
                                <h3><a href="product.php?id=5">EARING WIRELESS</a></h3>
                                <span class="price">$100</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                                            <div class="productFilter col-md-4 text-center" data-category="Table" data-start-price="960">
                        <div class="product">
                            <div class="product-grid" style="background-image:url(images/product-6.jpg);">
                                <div class="inner">
                                    <p>
                                        <a href="product.php?id=6" class="icon"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                                        <a href="product.php?id=6" class="icon"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="desc">
                                <h3><a href="product.php?id=6">SCULPTURAL COFFEE TABLE</a></h3>
                                <span class="price">$960</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                                            <div class="productFilter col-md-4 text-center" data-category="Chair" data-start-price="540">
                        <div class="product">
                            <div class="product-grid" style="background-image:url(images/product-7.jpg);">
                                <div class="inner">
                                    <p>
                                        <a href="product.php?id=7" class="icon"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                                        <a href="product.php?id=7" class="icon"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="desc">
                                <h3><a href="product.php?id=7">THE WW CHAIR</a></h3>
                                <span class="price">$540</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                                            <div class="productFilter col-md-4 text-center" data-category="Box" data-start-price="55">
                        <div class="product">
                            <div class="product-grid" style="background-image:url(images/product-8.jpg);">
                                <div class="inner">
                                    <p>
                                        <a href="product.php?id=8" class="icon"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                                        <a href="product.php?id=8" class="icon"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="desc">
                                <h3><a href="product.php?id=8">HIMITSU MONEY BOX</a></h3>
                                <span class="price">$55</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                                            <div class="productFilter col-md-4 text-center" data-category="Box" data-start-price="99">
                        <div class="product">
                            <div class="product-grid" style="background-image:url(images/product-9.jpg);">
                                <div class="inner">
                                    <p>
                                        <a href="product.php?id=9" class="icon"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                                        <a href="product.php?id=9" class="icon"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="desc">
                                <h3><a href="product.php?id=9">ARIANE PRIN</a></h3>
                                <span class="price">$99</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                                            <div class="productFilter col-md-4 text-center" data-category="Chair" data-start-price="350">
                        <div class="product">
                            <div class="product-grid" style="background-image:url(images/product-1.jpg);">
                                <div class="inner">
                                    <p>
                                        <a href="product.php?id=13" class="icon"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                                        <a href="product.php?id=13" class="icon"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="desc">
                                <h3><a href="product.php?id=13">HAUTEVILLE CONCRETE ROCKING CHAIR</a></h3>
                                <span class="price">$350</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                                        </div>
```

This is how my database/structure:

[image: Database]

Comment: Please provide how the product data is structured? And consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi @SomShekharMukherjee, thanks for reminding me, really appreciated